# En php se puede convertir un archivo pdf generado con fpdf a formato excel?

Tags: php, fpdf

Buen día, tengo un problema de como convertir archivos pdf (reportes) generado con fpdf a formato excel. He generado varios reportes en formato pdf y tienen bastantes cuadros, tablas y lo he podido realizar de manera eficaz con fpdf. El problema vino cuando ahora se requiere que esos reportes se puedan exportar al excel. Entonces he intentado poner esta etiqueta header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel") antes de generar el pdf pero no funciona, alguna idea de como poder convertir de pdf a excel?

He buscado ejemplos y mas hay de como exportar a excel desde php, pero casi nada de como hacer desde pdf a excel.

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (strlen(session_id())<1) 
  session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['log'])) {
    header("Location: ../vistas/iniciar.php"); 
}else{

$timestamp = time();
$filename = 'Export_Resumen_CH_' . $timestamp . '.xls';

//***************** inicio lineas para convertir a excel
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
echo "
        <html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">
        <head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\" /></head><body>";   
//***************** fin lineas para convertir a excel

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require('mc_table.php');
require "../config/Conex.php";

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ variables de filtro
$var_cod_est = isset($_GET['codest'])?limpiarCadena($_GET['codest']):'';
$var_cod = isset($_GET['cod'])?limpiarCadena($_GET['cod']):'';

//****************************** inicio
...
...
...
//****************************** fin
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(170);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,"TOTAL",0,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,$total_general,1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(10);
$pdf->Output('I','reporte_resumen.pdf');
ob_end_flush();
echo "</body></html>"; // lineas para convertir a excel

}
?>
```

Estas lineas "lineas para convertir a excel" (sin esas lineas exportar normal a pdf) las he colocado para poder exportar a excel pero no funciona. Tengo diseñado los reportes con fpdf, quiero aprovechar el diseño y pasarlo a excel.

Gracias por leer y cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar compañeros.

Comment: no se puede, nativa o directamente, la forma indirecta requiere mucho trabajo y no creo que aqui alguien vaya a crear una libreria solo para darte una respuesta, sin embargo por que en lugar de convertirlos de pdf a excel , no recreas el excel desde 0 con los datos que estas usando para crear el pdf?

Comment: Hola ArcanisGK507, gracias por la informacion. De tanto buscar encontre este articulo: https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-convert-PDF-files-into-Excel-format-using-PHP pero yo uso php nativo, no uso composer, entonces he estado buscando archivos o librerias que depende la libreria "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet" y no logro hacer correr ese ejemplo que al menos se aproxima a lo que necesito.

Comment: que no te funciona? si no sabes como implementarlo tienes que estudiar ... nosotros no podemos llegar y hacerte la implementacion .... puede ocurrir cualquiere error en el camino y no sabremos por que  ...

Comment: Si ya tienes el reporte en el paso previo, entonces podrías exportarlo a Excel (además de PDF). De lo contrario, muchos programas y librerías no son tan buenas reformateando los datos y tablas de PDF a Excel. Un programa (comercial) que me ha servido es Able2Extract, tiene "*batch*" para automatizar el proceso, solo que hay que pagar la licencia. Sin embargo, creo que te ahorrarías esfuerzo extra (y dinero) creando los archivos desde generador de reportes.

Comment: Gracias aeportugal, si convertir directamente a excel es mi ultima opcion. Lo que pasa es que si fuera un reporte con un encabezado y una tabla, sin dudar lo haria directamente en excel, son reportes muy personalizados con muchos detalles y resumenes y quería evitar reinventar la rueda si había alguna solución para convertir de pdf a excel, pero ya busque por toda lados y no encuentro algún ejemplo que funcione. En quora encontre un código con la clase IOFACTORY le falta el lector para pdf. Asi qué veré que más puedo averiguar como convertir sino al menos lo intente y no me quede con la duda.

Comment: Otra posible solución qué encontré aeportugal, es usar un exe pdftoexcel o algo así era pero eso ya es habilitar en el server si puede ejecutar prg, hay codigo en php de eso pero el tema es de permisos en el server, así que lo veo restringido para aplicarlo a un hosting externo.